# Linear transformation with the matrix $A$ (mirroring in a plane). Show that $AA = E$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across this question in my textbook, and I need some help...

$S$ is the linear transform that implies a mirroring in a plane. In a base $b$ the linear transformation $S$ has the matrix $A$. Show that $AA = E$, that $A$ is its own inverse.

**My thoughts**

First of all, the combination of two linear transformations gives the identity, if they are each others inverses. Given two mirroring effects in a plane we would simply come back to the point where we started, which implies that the second linear transformation "undos" the first, which implies that it is its inverse... But I don't understand how I can proceed from here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
Try to find the shape of $B=PAP^{-1}$ where $P$ is the matrix of change of basis from the basis b define in your question to the basis where the first vector is the normal of your hyperplane and the others belong to that hyperplane.
Therefore you should be able to prove that $B^2=I_n$ and hence $A^2=I_n$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will look into this. much appreciated!

Comment: My pleasure ! ;)